# Лихо: что первично?

Tags: этимология

Есть такой сказочный персонаж Лихо Одноглазое. И слово "лихо" является синонимом слов "горе", "беда", "несчастье". А что первично: фольклорный персонаж или абстрактное понятие?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересно происхождение слов с  корнем ЛИХ/ЛИШ. Исходным является греческий вариант со значением "остаток". Получалось, что лишний - это имеющий остаток, поэтому изобильный, хороший. И другой вариант: лишний - это являющийся остатком, поэтому несчастный, плохой.
Отсюда лихой, удалой наездник и лихой враг. От лихой (плохой) образуются названия болезней - лишай, лихорадка. Глагол "лишить" имел первоначальное значение "забрать остаток". Частица "лишь" также имеет значение "лишнего остатка" - это сравнительная степень "лише".

Comment: >сходным является греческий вариант  
  
интересно, каким боком тут вообще греческий?

Answer (score 2):

Имена фольклорных персонажей не могут появиться ниоткуда, они всегда мотивированы повседневной "неволшебной" лексикой. Слово *лихо* - это и существительное, и наречие, и краткое прилагательное. Все знают поговорку *лиха беда начало*, но немного затрудняются объяснить ее смысл. Все достаточно просто : начало - лихая беда, трудно сделать первый шаг, но потом дело само пойдет. 
Слова *зло* и *добро* точно так же могут быть разными частями речи.
Однокоренных слов и родственных у *лиха* очень много. *Лихва*, *лиходей*, *лихость*, *лишить*, *лишенец*... Сочетание *из лиха* (очень, чрезвычайно, много, более) со временем образовало прилагательное излишний.
Лихо - сверх меры, лишить - отобрать то, чего много или что вообще есть у человека. Семантика лиха - беды и лишения - несправедливости очень близка.

> А. С. Макаренко. Педагогическая поэма. Часть 1 (1933)
> Первый раз в жизни ударил человека. ― Ох, ты ж, лышенько! ― ахнул Калина Иванович.

................................
Разобравшись со смыслом слова *лихо*, начнем искать происхождение имени сказочного существа *Лиха Одноглазого* :
[image: Лихо Одноглазое]

Путем несложных умозаключений можно прийти к выводу, что Лихо первоначально было - **Лико**, и красовался на этом самом лике единственный глаз, как у знаменитых мифических циклопов.
Начинаю искать подтверждение моей догадки. Открываю в гугл.букс труды Афанасьева, известного собирателя фольклора :

> **ЛИКО ОДНОГЛАЗОЕ.**
> Слѣды преданія о Полифемѣ Вильгельмъ Гриммъ указываетъ въ сказкахъ и поэмахъ не только нѣмецкихъ, романскихъ, славянскихъ, но и финскихъ, татарскихъ (или тюркскихъ) и арабскихъ, заимствованныхъ изъ древне-персидскихъ источниковъ (см. Аміаntingen берлинской академіи наукъ 1857 года). Сверхъ сдѣланныхъ нами сравненій, можно указать еще на сказки венгерскую (стр. 148—150) и нѣмецкую (Deutsche Volksmarchen Гальтриха, No 36). Въ послѣдней общее преданіе нарушено тѣмъ, что великану даны два глаза; но это очевидно позднѣйшая неточность...

Лико-Лихо Одноглазое, какие еще загадки ты нам загадаешь?

Answer (score 1):

> А что первично: фольклорных персонаж или абстрактное понятие?

Первично имя нарицательное. Вообще в славянских традициях давать имена фольклорным персонажам по названиям всяких болезней и прочих гадостей ими олицетворяемых. Да и не только гадостей, даже явлений вообще.

Лихо (Лихорадка, Лихоманка  и проч.) образ обезобораживающей болезни, представлялась  безобразной девой, часто слепой или одноглазой. Перекочевало в сказки. Поэтому "Одноглазое" здесь скорее эпитет. Самостоятельного языческого божества или духа "Лихо *Одноглазое*" видимо не существовало.